# Align text CENTER when exporting to excel

Tags: asp.net

I am using the below two function to export my gridview data to excel.The problem is,data is exported completely but right aligned,i need it center aligned,i am not able to figure it out..Can anyone help me in this regard.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public static void GenerateExcel(GridView gv)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Leave_Report.xls");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

            using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                using (HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
                {
                    //  Create a table to contain the grid
                    Table table = new Table();

                    //  include the gridline settings
                    table.GridLines = gv.GridLines;

                    //  add the header row to the table
                    if (gv.HeaderRow != null)
                    {
                        PrepareControlForExport(gv.HeaderRow);
                        table.Rows.Add(gv.HeaderRow);
                    }
                    //Make Header Coloruful

                    for (int j = 0; j < gv.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                        //Apply style to Individual Cells
                        gv.HeaderRow.Cells[j].Style.Add("background-color", "#4DB4EE");

                    }

                    //  add each of the data rows to the table
                    foreach (GridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
                    {
                        PrepareControlForExport(row);
                        table.Rows.Add(row);
                    }

                    //  add the footer row to the table
                    if (gv.FooterRow != null)
                    {
                        PrepareControlForExport(gv.FooterRow);
                        table.Rows.Add(gv.FooterRow);
                    }

                    //  render the table into the htmlwriter
                    table.RenderControl(htw);

                    //  render the htmlwriter into the response
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sw.ToString());
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
                }
            }


        }


private static void PrepareControlForExport(Control control)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < control.Controls.Count; i++)
        {
            Control current = control.Controls[i];
            if (current is LinkButton)
            {
                control.Controls.Remove(current);
                control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current as LinkButton).Text));
            }
            else if (current is ImageButton)
            {
                control.Controls.Remove(current);
                control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current as ImageButton).AlternateText));
            }
            else if (current is HyperLink)
            {
                control.Controls.Remove(current);
                control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current as HyperLink).Text));
            }
            else if (current is DropDownList)
            {
                control.Controls.Remove(current);
                control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current as DropDownList).SelectedItem.Text));
            }
            else if (current is CheckBox)
            {
                control.Controls.Remove(current);
                control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current as CheckBox).Checked ? "True" : "False"));
            }

            if (current.HasControls())
            {
                PrepareControlForExport(current);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What you have tried ???????????

Comment: i am trying to work with  wSheet.get_Range("B3", "B3").HorizontalAlignment = Constants.xlCenter; but for that i have to change whole function,i am trying to find ways in the above mentioned function to align text to center

Comment: please review the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
wSheet.get_Range("B3", "B3").HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlign.Center;
```

instead of

```
wSheet.get_Range("B3", "B3").HorizontalAlignment = Constants.xlCenter;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
        {
            foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                cell.Attributes.CssStyle["text-align"] = "center";
            }
        }
```